# Java Applet output

Tags: java, applet

I have the following code to print a flag in Java Applet, the last statement prints the coordinates of a polygon, when I run the code it prints the coordinates **14 times**, which is not logical, the loop should iterate only **7** times

```
import java.applet.*;  
import java.awt.*;  
public class New1 extends Applet
{  
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {  
        super.setSize(600,600);
        int centerX=110;
        int centerY=225;
        int outerCircleDiameter = 120;
        int innerCircleDiameter = 70;
        int outerCircleRadius = outerCircleDiameter / 2;
        int innerCircleRadius = innerCircleDiameter / 2;
        int[] xPoints = new int[14];
        int[] yPoints = new int[14];
        double angle = Math.PI / 2; 
        double angleIncrement = 2 * Math.PI / 7; 

        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) 
        {
            int radius = i % 2 == 0 ? outerCircleRadius : innerCircleRadius;
            int x = (int) (centerX + Math.cos(angle) * radius);
            int y = (int) (centerY - Math.sin(angle) * radius);
            xPoints[i] = x;
            yPoints[i] = y;
            angle += angleIncrement;
        }
        angleIncrement = 2 * Math.PI / 7; 
        angle = Math.PI / 2;
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 14);
        int[] xiPoints = new int[7];
        int[] yiPoints = new int[7];
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
        {
            int x = (int) (centerX + Math.cos(angle) * innerCircleRadius);
            int y = (int) (centerY - Math.sin(angle) * innerCircleRadius);
            xiPoints[i] = x;
            yiPoints[i] = y;
            angle += angleIncrement;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("("+xiPoints[i]+","+yiPoints[i]+")");
        }
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillPolygon(xiPoints, yiPoints, 7);        
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawOval(centerX - innerCircleRadius, centerY - innerCircleRadius, innerCircleDiameter, innerCircleDiameter);
    }
}
```

when i run the applet i get the following output from the print statement:

```
(110,190)
(82,203)
(75,232)
(94,256)
(125,256)
(144,232)
(137,203)
(110,190)
(82,203)
(75,232)
(94,256)
(125,256)
(144,232)
(137,203)
```

does anyone know the reason for that ?

Comment: Because the `paint` method is executed each and every time the applet needs to be repainted.  In your test, `paint` was executed twice.